# iOS app to access database from my own website

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I own a JSP website for listing books stored in my own database in the same website. I'm planning to develop an iPhone app to access this database and display book list and book details.

My questions are:

1. If I have to use web services, where
   should I start to develop these web
   services using eclipse.
2. How to access these data and display
   them in a list.
3. I want to cache data extracted and
   store it locally in iPhone, so when
   no Internet connectivity available
   the user can view these data
   offline. Is there a database engine
   embedded in iPhone to sotre such
   relational data.

Thanks you all,

Answer (score 0):

1. Develop the webservice with what you know. PHP, Python, asp.net, java.
2. Access the data using [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) GET POST methods. Many application are using the [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/).
3. iPhone as the [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/) database embed in it operating system. You can find plenty of tutorial on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

- 1 & 2 Define the services you are going to provided from you website, choose a web service protocol, JSON is generally easy to use, so does xmlrpc.
- 3 Use core data to cache it locally, if no internet connection, you can fetch the data from core data